# While loops in Unity C# making the PlayMode never load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made this code:

```
public GameObject prefabBullet;
public GameObject[] places;

public int amountOfCycles;

public float baseTimeBetweenCycles;

public float timeBetweenCycles;

private int amountOfCyclesThatAlreadyHappened;

private int value = 0;

private int random;

void Start() {
    random = Random.Range(0, places.Length + 1);
    amountOfCyclesThatAlreadyHappened = 0;
}


void Update()
{
    while(amountOfCyclesThatAlreadyHappened < amountOfCycles)
    {
        while(value < places.Length && timeBetweenCycles < 0) 
        {
            if(value != random)
           {
            GameObject bulletGO = Instantiate(prefabBullet, places[value].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            timeBetweenCycles = baseTimeBetweenCycles;
           }
           value++;
           break;
        }

            if(timeBetweenCycles > 0)
           {
            timeBetweenCycles -= Time.deltaTime;
           }

            if(value > places.Length)
           {
               amountOfCyclesThatAlreadyHappened += 1;
               random = Random.Range(0, places.Length + 1);
               value = 0;
           }
    }

}
```

i do not think I did one of those loops infinite, as it sets eventually the value to 0 and both lops *should* eventually stop being true, as ++ exists in both loops. Anyone could tell me what is causing those loops to be infinite?

Answer (score 3):

Your outer `while` is looping forever because `amountOfCyclesThatAlreadyHappened` never increments.

The only place in your code where `amountOfCyclesThatAlreadyHappened` could conceivably increment is inside this case: `if(value > places.Length)`

However, that case occurs inside a while loop with condition `while(value < places.Length && timeBetweenCycles < 0)`

As you can see, your if and while conditionals have opposite conditions relating to value, so the only way the inner `if` would ever be true is if `value` changed during loop execution before you hit that `if` block. However, the only place this happens, `value++;`, has a `break;` immediately after it so the loop doesn't continue on.

Comment: I dont really undertstand what you said, I know that I forgot to put a = ( I put < instead of =< )

Comment: What part did you not understand?